# Wicket : org.apache.wicket.markup.MarkupNotFoundException

Tags: java, html, apache, wicket

WelcomePage.java

```
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.WebPage;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.basic.Label;
import org.apache.wicket.model.Model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.basic.Label;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.navigation.paging.PagingNavigator;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.repeater.Item;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.repeater.data.DataView;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.repeater.data.ListDataProvider;
import org.apache.wicket.model.IModel;
import org.apache.wicket.model.Model;
import com.ui.*;



 public class WelcomePage extends WebPage{

 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

 public WelcomePage(){

    Contact contact = null;
    final List<Contact> list = new ArrayList<Contact>();

    char character;

    // a - z
    for(int i = 97; i < 123; i++){
        character = (char) i;
        contact = new Contact(String.valueOf(character));
        list.add(contact);
    }

    final DataView<Contact> dataView =
        new DataView<Contact>("simple", new ListDataProvider<Contact>(list)){

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public void populateItem(final Item<Contact> item){
                final Contact user = item.getModelObject();
                item.add(new Label("id", user.getId()));
            }
        };

    dataView.setItemsPerPage(10);

    add(dataView);

    add(new PagingNavigator("navigator", dataView));
}

}
```

WelcomePage.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

<span wicket:id="lbl"> </span>


<wicket:extend>

<table cellspacing="0" class="dataview">
 <tbody>
   <tr wicket:id="simple">
     <td><span wicket:id="id">Test ID</span></td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<div wicket:id="navigator"></div>

</wicket:extend>
</body>
</html>
```

The above code is for displaying Dataview - https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/A+Simple+DataView+Example

When I am executing the above code I am getting the following error..

```
 Last cause: Can not determine Markup. Component is not yet connected to a parent. [Page class = com.kaiinos.kriti.ui.WelcomePage, id = 12, render count = 1]
```

Stacktrace -
    Root cause:

```
org.apache.wicket.markup.MarkupNotFoundException: Can not determine Markup. Component is not yet connected to a parent. [Page class = com.kaiinos.kriti.ui.WelcomePage, id = 12, render count = 1]
 at org.apache.wicket.Component.getMarkup(Component.java:751)
 at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRender(Component.java:2378)
 at org.apache.wicket.Component.render(Component.java:2341)
 at org.apache.wicket.Page.renderPage(Page.java:1018)
 at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.WebPageRenderer.renderPage(WebPageRenderer.java:124)
 at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.WebPageRenderer.respond(WebPageRenderer.java:236)
 at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.RenderPageRequestHandler.respond(RenderPageRequestHandler.java:175)
 at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle$HandlerExecutor.respond(RequestCycle.java:895)
 at org.apache.wicket.request.RequestHandlerStack.execute(RequestHandlerStack.java:64)
 at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.execute(RequestCycle.java:265)
 at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequest(RequestCycle.java:222)
 at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequestAndDetach(RequestCycle.java:293)
 at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequestCycle(WicketFilter.java:261)
 at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequest(WicketFilter.java:203)
 at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doFilter(WicketFilter.java:284)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
 at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099)
 at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Edit - Modified the java code and html but getting the same error.I am just a beginner.
Any help would be appreciated.Thankyou in advance.

Comment: Check your markup, it's invalid: the xml declaration has to come first.

Comment: ... and you're using <wicket:extend>, does our BasePage have its markup?

Comment: The exception says "WelcomePage" but your Java code is about Sub1Page. In addition your HTML is incomplete. I needs closing elements, like </body> and </html. Maybe even more. Also `<wicket:extend>` should be used when the page extends another one that has `<wicket:child>` inside it. I'd recommend you to start with Wicket's user guide: http://wicket.apache.org/learn/#guide

Comment: Thankyou.. Edited the code.. But can you please explain how to use <wicket:child> I dint understand..where to insert?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things wrong with your code as provided. If you want to learn how to write wicket applications (instead of asking for help with clearly defined questions) StackOverflow is not the right place for you. As @martin-g suggested, you might want to look into the [Wicket user guide](https://wicket.apache.org/learn/#guide)

As for your current code:

- `<wicket:extend>` defines a set of html that takes the place of the `<wicket:child>` tag in the parent component's markup. That means that anything outside the `<wicket:extend>`, such as your `<span wicket:id="lbl"> </span>`, gets ignored.
- using `<wicket:extend>` suggests that there is a parent component with an associated HTML file containing a `<wicket:child>`. The parent component for your `WelcomePage` is Wicket's `WebPage` but it has no associated HTML file. This means that you can't use `<wicket:extend>` in your `WelcomePage`.
- The constructor of your `WelcomePage` is called `Sub1Page`. I'm guessing this is a leftover from your other code? In any case, it is invalid.

Try rewriting the HTML for your `WelcomePage` to something like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:wicket>
<body>

<table cellspacing="0" class="dataview">
 <tbody>
   <tr wicket:id="simple">
     <td><span wicket:id="id">Test ID</span></td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<div wicket:id="navigator"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thankyou so much for the explanation.... Modified Html code as suggested but getting error as     -        Last cause: Unable to find component with id 'simple' in [Page class = com.kaiinos.kriti.ui.WelcomePage, id = 0, render count = 1]
 Expected: ':simple'.
 Found with similar names: ''

Comment: That exception means that your html references a `wicket:id="simple"` but you haven't added a component whose `id` is "simple". In your example you are constructing a `DataView dataView` with id "simple" and adding it to the page so I'm not sure why this error would come up.
Are you sure you're still adding that component to the page and is the id still the same as the wicket:id in the html?